# Does nodetool tablestats Space used (live) gives Total size of the table on Cluster or Total Size of the table on the node its executed?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

On executing `nodetool tablestats`, there are many output metrics that are generated for a given table.
Are the metrics like SSTable count, Space used (live) and Space used (total)
reflecting the counts and size of table on particular node or its a aggregation of metrics from entire cluster. If its not cluster wide how do we extrapolate "space used" to reflect cluster wide usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the nodetool commands are showing the data for a current node, or how the other nodes look like from a current node...

To get a cluster wide statistics you need to collect data from all nodes, for example by scraping data via JMX into monitoring system, or use something like [metrics collector for Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/metric-collector-for-apache-cassandra) together with Prometheus and Grafana